# Quick Add to cart redirect to product page for no reason

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When i click “add to cart” button, it redirect me to product page without reason..this happend on all site after updating woocommerce plugin..is there any fix for this…is there myb any php function for fixing it..

Comment: Check your settings , check console for errors, debug for errors. I maintain multiple woo stores with latests version and dont face any problems so its probably on yourside problem. Check compability with your theme, plugins. Deactivated all plugins and see if the issue is there. Switch to storefront theme and see if problem is there.

Comment: I tried everything, but everything, from settings to deacitaving plugins, but it can be only woocommerce plugin problem or even with theme compability...

Comment: on my other sites, same thing happend..

Comment: Did you switch to storefront theme ?

Comment: nope, theme stayed the same its woodmart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to reactivate woocommerce plugin and it will works again. If somebody get the same problem like me this is your answer.